# Noisy fan, can it be mechanical?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, hardware-failure, fan, cooling

I have a Dell Latitude E5530. Recently the fan has started making aggressive buzzing noises. Not all the time, but as soon I'm running a Matlab computation or watching a movie - whenever the load is slightly above idle, it will start to make noises. The core temp is completely fine when it starts, 55-59 degrees celsius.

It started a while after I upgraded from Ubuntu 12 to Ubuntu 14. Apparently it is fairly common for Dell and Ubuntu to have some driver issues. But I opened it up today to clean out the fan again (with compressed air), I noticed that it actually started to make the buzzing sound just by being propelled by the compressed air at certain angles.

I'm not sure how a fan is supposed to feel when you press it, but I could detect a super duper slight nanometer wiggle when I pressed the fan. I didn't really want to dig deeper, since this laptop doesn't really have the most easily reachable innards. But could the issue be that something has gotten slightly bent from lifting the laptop weirdly?

How would I diagnose this? If it is mechanical, like it has been bent slightly, would it be DIY fixable?

edit: I actually recall a few times where it started making a noise, and lifting it in the parts FAR AWAY from the fan area actually made it stop briefly - as if I had bent it back into shape.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's an issue with how you've handled the laptop, it just sounds like the bearing has gone bad or may have lost it's lubrication. You can either replace the fan, or you can try re-lubricating the fan bearing. I've never tried to oil a bearing on a computer fan, I've always simply replaced it. If you want to try to oil it, [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/quiet-noisy-computer-fans-with-a-drop-of-oil/) guide should explain it well enough.